# SAS: Delete all .txt files in a folder

Tags: sas

I need to delete all text files form a directory. The following program works fine for the file listed (eg:file.txt), but when I try to use *.txt it doesn't work. Am I missing something or is there a better way to delete all txt files in a directory.

```
data _null_; 
      fname = "_files"; 
      rc = filename(fname,"&path\file.txt"); 
      if rc = 0 and fexist(fname) then         
         rc = fdelete(fname); 
      rc = filename(fname);
   run;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are a fan of macros.. the code below should do the same.

```
 options mlogic;
    %macro delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(folder);
       filename filelist "&folder";
       data _null_;
          dir_id = dopen('filelist');
          total_members = dnum(dir_id);
          do i = 1 to total_members;  
             member_name = dread(dir_id,i);
             if scan(lowcase(member_name),2,'.')='txt' then do; 
              file_id = mopen(dir_id,member_name,'i',0);
              if file_id > 0 then do; 
                freadrc = fread(file_id);
                rc = fclose(file_id);
                rc = filename('delete',member_name,,,'filelist');
                rc = fdelete('delete');
             end;
             rc = fclose(file_id);
          end;
          end;
          rc = dclose(dir_id);
       run;
    %mend;


    %delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(C:\try)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will definitely try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a wildcard with fdelete.  You either need to loop over all of the files in the directory, or you can use an x command

```
x 'del &path.\*.txt';
```

or similar depending on your OS (but it is OS dependent, and requires `XCMD` permission.

Here's the loop:

```
%let path=d:\temp;
filename filrf "&path.";
data _null_;
  did = dopen('filrf');
  memcount = dnum(did);
  do while (memcount>0);
    fname = dread(did,memcount);
    if scan(lowcase(fname),2,'.')='txt' then do;
        rcref = filename('fref',catx('\',"&path.",fname));
        rcdel = fdelete('fref');
    end;
    memcount+-1;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I will try to loop over the files.

Comment: X would be OS specific - X works in both but it's executing a system command so obviously 'del' vs 'rm'.  The fdelete method should be OS independent, although not all OSes necessarily work the same in how FDELETE works - i'm not sure if in a VAX or something this would be the same.

Comment: Why 'stop;' is there?

Comment: @D.O. Because otherwise the data step loop will never have a reason to terminate (since we're not hitting an end-of-dataset or end-of-file marker).

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your answer!